# Convert Oracle to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, oracle, view

I want to create a view in SQL that is already created in Oracle and i have the following  where clause script in Oracle:

```
where (wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr = orguserfield.orgnbr(+)
       and upper(orguserfield.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WREG'
       and orguserfield.userfieldcd = userfieldvalue.userfieldcd(+)
       and orguserfield.value = userfieldvalue.userfieldvalue(+)
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr = orguserfield_c.orgnbr(+)
       and upper(orguserfield_c.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WBRN'
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr = orguserfield_e.orgnbr(+)
       and upper(orguserfield_e.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WBRS'
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr = orguserfield_h.orgnbr(+)
       and upper(orguserfield_h.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WHBN'
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr = orguserfield_i.orgnbr(+)
       and upper(orguserfield_i.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WSIZ'
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.branchorgnbr = orguserfield_j.orgnbr(+)
       and upper(orguserfield_j.userfieldcd(+)) = 'WDIV'
       and orguserfield_j.userfieldcd = userfieldvalue_l.userfieldcd(+)
       and orguserfield_j.value = userfieldvalue_l.userfieldvalue(+)
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.acctnbr = acctacctrolepers.acctnbr(+)
       and upper(acctacctrolepers.acctrolecd(+)) = 'PMGR'
       and acctacctrolepers.persnbr = persview.persnbr(+)
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.acctnbr = acctacctrolepers_c.acctnbr(+)
       and acctacctrolepers_c.acctrolecd(+) = 'OLOF'
       and acctacctrolepers_c.persnbr = persview_d.persnbr(+)
      )
  and (wh_acctcommon.acctnbr = acctacctrolepers_e.acctnbr(+)
       and acctacctrolepers_e.acctrolecd(+) = 'COFF'
       and acctacctrolepers_e.persnbr = persview_e.persnbr(+)
      );
```

Could anyone please help me in converting this Oracle script to SQL Server?

TIA

Comment: Search how to create ansi style outer joins

Comment: @JamesZ do you know what does this represents: acctacctrolepers_c.acctrolecd(+) = 'OLOF' ? Basically the plus sign here

Comment: That is outer join in the oracle syntax

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks, but what does acctrolecd(+) = 'OLOF does that mean with left outer join, use AND acctrolecd = 'OLOF' ?

Comment: It means the value in acctrolecd must be 'OLOF'